# Reuse the SUB Query Columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following SQL,

```
SELECT  U.ID AS UserID
    ,U.LoginName AS Name
    ,PV.Time AS [Time]
    ,PV.URL AS [Url]
    ,P.Name AS [Product 1 Name]
    ,P.SKU AS [Product 1 SKU]
    ,P.ModelNumber AS [Product 1 Model Number]
    ,P2.Name AS [Product 2 Name]
    ,P2.SKU AS [Product 2 SKU]
    ,P2.ModelNumber AS [Product 2 Model Number]
    ,ISNULL((select TOP 1 Value from AttributesValues AV INNER JOIN Attributes A ON AV.AttributeID = A.ID WHERE AV.ProductID = P.ID AND A.RetailerID = 23 AND A.CODE = 'metadata-department'),'') AS Department
        ,ISNULL((select TOP 1 Value from AttributesValues AV INNER JOIN Attributes A ON AV.AttributeID = A.ID WHERE AV.ProductID = P.ID AND A.RetailerID = 23 AND A.CODE = 'metadata-group'),'') AS Department
        ,ISNULL((select TOP 1 Value from AttributesValues AV INNER JOIN Attributes A ON AV.AttributeID = A.ID WHERE AV.ProductID = P.ID AND A.RetailerID = 23 AND A.CODE = 'metadata-subgroup'),'') AS SubGroup
        ,C.Browser AS [Browser]
        ,C.BrowserVersion AS [Browser Version]
        ,C.IPAddress AS [IP Address]
        ,C.UserAgent AS [User Agent]
        ,C.UserLanguage AS [User Language]
        ,PV.PageType AS [Page Type]
FROM    PageVisits PV
        INNER JOIN Users U ON U.ID = PV.UserID
        INNER JOIN Clients C ON C.ID = PV.ClientID
        INNER JOIN Products P ON P.id = PV.P1ID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Products P2 ON P2.id = PV.P2ID 
WHERE   P.RetailerID = 23 
        AND PV.UserID IS NOT NULL
        AND PV.PageType IN ('Product','Compare Products')
        AND PV.[Time] >= '{0}' AND PV.[Time] < '{1}'
```

The problem is this sub-query,

```
,ISNULL((select TOP 1 Value from AttributesValues AV 
 INNER JOIN Attributes A ON AV.AttributeID = A.ID 
 WHERE AV.ProductID = P.ID AND A.RetailerID = 23 
 AND A.CODE = 'metadata-department'),'') AS Department
```

I used here 3 times. The only difference is the `A.CODE =`. How can I improve this

Comment: (unrelated to the question:) `TOP` should be used with `ORDER BY` only.

Comment: Create a view to shorten the subquery

Comment: In the subqueries, you have TOP without ORDER BY.

Comment: prepare temporary table of subquery

Comment: @ypercube, is this makes any difference?

Comment: @KobbyPemson, I want to improve the performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use `ORDER BY` with `TOP`. Otherwise you will get indeterminate results, depending on how the SQL engine will fetch the related rows.

If the `TOP 1` are not really needed, i.e. if the subqueries would always return 1 (or 0) rows anyway, without the TOP, then you could use `OUTER APPLY` with `MAX()`:

```
SELECT
    ---
        ,COALESCE(X.Department, '') AS Department
        ,COALESCE(X.[Group], '')    AS [Group]
        ,COALESCE(X.SubGroup, '')   AS SubGroup
    ---
FROM    PageVisits PV
        INNER JOIN Users U ON U.ID = PV.UserID
        INNER JOIN Clients C ON C.ID = PV.ClientID
        INNER JOIN Products P ON P.id = PV.P1ID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Products P2 ON P2.id = PV.P2ID 
        OUTER APPLY
        ( SELECT   MAX(CASE WHEN A.CODE = 'metadata-department' THEN AV.Value END) 
                      AS Department
                  ,MAX(CASE WHEN A.CODE = 'metadata-group' THEN AV.Value END) 
                      AS [Group]
                  ,MAX(CASE WHEN A.CODE = 'metadata-subqroup' THEN AV.Value END) 
                      AS SubGroup
          FROM    AttributesValues AV 
                  INNER JOIN Attributes A ON AV.AttributeID = A.ID 
          WHERE   AV.ProductID = P.ID 
            AND   A.RetailerID = 23 
        ) X
WHERE   
    --- ;
```

Answer (score 3):

You should first try to build indexes for the query:

```
create index on Attributes(RetailerId, Code, Id);
create index on AttributeValues(AttributeId, ProductId, Value);
```

The processing for the subquery should then just be a couple of index lookups.

Comment: OK. But Someone told me that Indexes will make INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE slow?

Comment: @user960567 It depends on the columns interested in those statements and on the columns set in the index definition.

Comment: @user960567 . . . Indexes will slow down data insertion operations.  Whether to use them depends on the relative loads on the system.  The question says nothing about data modification loads.

Comment: +1, the index suggestions are very useful. @user960567, indexes usually boost the SELECT queries that use them (and some INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE as well) with a huge performance benefit. The slowing down of INSERT (and some UPDATE/DELETE) is usually very small.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a CTE, which is basically an inline view to avoid retyping the query, but it won't actually change the query being executed 3 times, it will just tidy up the code:

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  AV.ProductID, AV.Value, A.Code 
    FROM    AttributesValues AV 
            INNER JOIN Attributes A ON AV.AttributeID = A.ID 
    WHERE   A.RetailerID = 23
)
SELECT  U.ID AS UserID
        ,U.LoginName AS Name
        ,PV.Time AS [Time]
        ,PV.URL AS [Url]
        ,P.Name AS [Product 1 Name]
        ,P.SKU AS [Product 1 SKU]
        ,P.ModelNumber AS [Product 1 Model Number]
        ,P2.Name AS [Product 2 Name]
        ,P2.SKU AS [Product 2 SKU]
        ,P2.ModelNumber AS [Product 2 Model Number]
        ,ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 Value FROM CTE WHERE CTE.ProductID = P.ID AND CTE.CODE = 'metadata-department'),'') AS Department
        ,ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 Value FROM CTE WHERE CTE.ProductID = P.ID AND CTE.CODE = 'metadata-group'),'') AS [Group]
        ,ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 Value FROM CTE WHERE CTE.ProductID = P.ID AND CTE.CODE = 'metadata-subgroup'),'') AS SubGroup
        ,C.Browser AS [Browser]
        ,C.BrowserVersion AS [Browser Version]
        ,C.IPAddress AS [IP Address]
        ,C.UserAgent AS [User Agent]
        ,C.UserLanguage AS [User Language]
        ,PV.PageType AS [Page Type]
FROM    PageVisits PV
        INNER JOIN Users U ON U.ID = PV.UserID
        INNER JOIN Clients C ON C.ID = PV.ClientID
        INNER JOIN Products P ON P.id = PV.P1ID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Products P2 ON P2.id = PV.P2ID 
WHERE   P.RetailerID = 23 
        AND PV.UserID IS NOT NULL
        AND PV.PageType IN ('Product','Compare Products')
        AND PV.[Time] >= '{0}' AND PV.[Time] < '{1}'
```

It is also worth noting you have `TOP 1` with no order by, which will give you non-deterministic results (unless there are unique constraints to ensure there is only one possible row to return).

I'd also be inclined to rewrite this as a JOIN to reduce the number of table reads on `AttributesValues` and `Attributes`. You can do this by using PIVOT on the attribute values:

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  AV.ProductID, 
            AV.Value, 
            A.Code ,
            RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AV.ProductID, A.Code ORDER BY AV.Value)
    FROM    AttributesValues AV 
            INNER JOIN Attributes A ON AV.AttributeID = A.ID 
    WHERE   A.RetailerID = 23
    AND     AV.Code IN ('metadata-department', 'metadata-group', 'metadata-subgroup')
), AV AS
(   SELECT  pvt.ProductID, 
            pvt.[metadata-department], 
            pvt.[metadata-group], 
            pvt.[metadata-subgroup]
    FROM    CTE
            PIVOT
            (   MAX(Value)
                FOR Code IN ([metadata-department], [metadata-group], [metadata-subgroup])
            ) pvt
    WHERE   pvt.RowNumber = 1
)
SELECT  U.ID AS UserID
        ,U.LoginName AS Name
        ,PV.Time AS [Time]
        ,PV.URL AS [Url]
        ,P.Name AS [Product 1 Name]
        ,P.SKU AS [Product 1 SKU]
        ,P.ModelNumber AS [Product 1 Model Number]
        ,P2.Name AS [Product 2 Name]
        ,P2.SKU AS [Product 2 SKU]
        ,P2.ModelNumber AS [Product 2 Model Number]
        ,ISNULL(AV.[metadata-department],'') AS Department
        ,ISNULL(AV.[metadata-group],'') AS [Group]
        ,ISNULL(AV.[metadata-subgroup],'') AS SubGroup
        ,C.Browser AS [Browser]
        ,C.BrowserVersion AS [Browser Version]
        ,C.IPAddress AS [IP Address]
        ,C.UserAgent AS [User Agent]
        ,C.UserLanguage AS [User Language]
        ,PV.PageType AS [Page Type]
FROM    PageVisits PV
        INNER JOIN Users U ON U.ID = PV.UserID
        INNER JOIN Clients C ON C.ID = PV.ClientID
        INNER JOIN Products P ON P.id = PV.P1ID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Products P2 ON P2.id = PV.P2ID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN AV ON AV.ProductID = p.ID
WHERE   P.RetailerID = 23 
        AND PV.UserID IS NOT NULL
        AND PV.PageType IN ('Product','Compare Products')
        AND PV.[Time] >= '{0}' AND PV.[Time] < '{1}'
```

*N>B* you may wish to change the `ORDER BY` in the `ROW_NUMBER` to affect which value is returned for each combination of productID and Code (if this is unique the order by is irrelevant though)*